# InstallShield Custom Dialog, WaitOnDialog() always return -1 (DLG_ERR)

Tags: dialog, return-value, installshield, customdialog, installscript

I'm currently doing a Custom Dialog to handle locked file situation on an InstallScript project. I know there are built-in functions like SdException() to handle this case but this is a requirement to avoid the case where user accidentally chose to ignore the situation.

In summary, I initialize the EzDefineDialog() and then call WaitOnDialog() to display the dialog but it always returns -1.

The following is my code:

```
prototype NUMBER LockedFile(string /*FilePath*/);

//[[ ID_DATA
#define IDD_VER 300
#define ID_NAME_LOCKED_FILE "LockedFile"
#define ID_TITLE_LOCKED_FILE "Default Dialog Title\nDefault Title message"
#define ID_TEMPLATE_LOCKED_FILE 12345
//]]

//[[ ID_SYMBOLS
#define BT_PostPone 1303 
#define BT_Retry    1304 
#define BT_Abort    1305

#define IDC_TEXT1_LOCKED_FILE   1301

//]]

function NUMBER LockedFile(szFile /*FilePath*/)

NUMBER  nId;        // contains the return code of WaitOnDialog 
NUMBER  nResult;    // contains the return code of LockedFile
BOOL    bDone;      // tells if the dialog is to be closed
INT     hwndDlg;    // the handle of the dialog itself
STRING  szTitle;    // dialog's title
STRING  szDlg;      // the name of the dialog
STRING  szMessage;  // message to display on dialog
NUMBER  nTemplate;  // variable to store the template to be used for this dialog

begin

// Specify a name to identify the custom dialog in this installation.
szDlg = ID_NAME_LOCKED_FILE;
nTemplate = ID_TEMPLATE_LOCKED_FILE;



if (EzDefineDialog (szDlg, ISUSER, "", nTemplate) = DLG_ERR) then
    MessageBox("Fail to initialize the Locked Dialog for "+szFile, SEVERE);
    abort;
endif;

bDone = FALSE;
while (!bDone)
    nId = WaitOnDialog(szDlg);

    switch (nId)
        case DLG_INIT:
            // first internal InstallShield intitialise
            hwndDlg = CmdGetHwndDlg( szDlg );
            SdGeneralInit(szDlg, hwndDlg, 0, "");
        case DLG_CLOSE:
            // The user clicked the window's Close button.
            Do (EXIT);
        case DLG_ERR:
            MessageBox ("Unable to display dialog. Setup canceled.", SEVERE);
            abort;  
        case BT_PostPone:
            // user clicked PostPone button, the operation will be carried out after reboot
            bDone = TRUE;
            nResult =  1;
        case BT_Retry:
            // user clicked retry button, retry the operation immediately
            bDone = TRUE;
            nResult = 2;
        case BT_Abort:
            // user clicked abort button, abort the installation
            bDone = TRUE;
            nResult = 3;
        default:    
            // user do something else
            bDone = TRUE;
            nResult = -1;
     endswitch;
endwhile;

EndDialog(szDlg); // Close the dialog box. 

ReleaseDialog(szDlg);   // Free the dialog box from memory.

return nResult;

end;
```

I have double checked and make use that the ISResourceID in both Dialogs and Direct Editor to be 12345, which was passed into `EzDefineDialog (szDlg, ISUSER, "", nTemplate)` as nTemplate. The Dialog name (szDlg) is also double checked.

I want to know where I did wrong. How can I display my Custom Dialog ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, I referenced the dialog by its name, not `resourceID`. The `WaitOnDialog()` function always returned `DLG_ERR` until I changed the dialog's `resourceID` to `0`.

Perhaps this helps...